# using design library requires using theme.appcompat

Tags: android, android-layout

After trying all the possibilites from online came here for the help

I am trying for TextInputLayout(android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout) for floating edittext but i got this error message

[image: Error Message link]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="1"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: the gradle file link]

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

[Manifest file link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKW0P.png)

Comment: can you post AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Try this once Build -> Clean Project ; Build -> Rebuild Project ; Run -> Run

Comment: Why did you use an image for the Gradle file?

Comment: when i tried to paste the code i uploaded in gig-gag format, so i thought image could be better

Answer (score 0):

make sure you themes extends `Theme.AppCompact` in your styles.xml

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    ...
</style>
```

Comment: I am using the same theme

Comment: And theme is set in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes it is also same, please check the links for gradel and error message

Answer (score 0):

Add this also in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
```

and in manifest, for your activity you have to have this

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

your activity should have theme

<activity
        android:name=".verticle.common.login.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: You don't need to compile the v4 library... The v7 and design libraries include it

Comment: But i need design support of TextInpuyLayout, problem starts by adding this dependence 
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

Comment: @jithendrasai can you add AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @jithendrasai problem with your activity, you didnt have theme for your activity, see my edited answer

Comment: I have theme for my activity

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`. `TextInputLayout` requires `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: you can use EditText also

Comment: I tried TextInputEditText it causes ** Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.**

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I had issues with EditText which got solved after switching to TextInputEditText. Thought that could work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, for your mainfest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And in your resource->style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

And in your activity change to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved mine by adding a `Theme.AppCompat...` theme in my activity on the Manifest file like that:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.WelcomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```